# Debugging WPF in Offline mode

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, networking

How can I easily switch between debugging my (WPF) application with access to internet and without it?

I'm using VS 2015 Ultimate.

Comment: Are you asking how to programatically disable the network connection on your computer?

Comment: I'm asking if I can disable network-access conveniently just for the application that I'm debugging (preferably within VS) without manually adding a firewall rule and/or disabling my internet connection.

Comment: You can use a batch file to edit your Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts file to block certain DNS names by redirecting them to address 0.0.0.0.  As long as you know the domain names being connected to and have local admin rights, it should work.